# Matplotlib tick frequency

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, graph, graphing

I have a list of dates that I am plotting against a list of scores.

```
date = ['5/25/2015', '5/25/2015', '5/3/2015', '2/4/2015', '2/1/2015', '1/25/2015', '12/31/2014', '10/9/2014', '8/26/2014', '7/24/2014', '7/3/2014', .....]`

scores = [6.497, 14.915, 9.911, 9.908, 11.99, 10.993, 14.987, .... ]
```

with an equal number of both.

I am generating a graph as follows:

```
figScore = plt.figure() 
plt.plot(range(len(Scores)), Scores)
plt.xticks(range(len(Scores)), date, size = "small", rotation = 90)
plt.tight_layout()

name = 'plot.png'
figScore.savefig(name)
```

(no image due to <10 rep)

However, I can not change the tick frequency. I would like the x-labels to appear every 5 dates on the x-axis. I have tried multiple methods to fix this and it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the simplest way to do it, but one way would be to just make an extra list that is mostly blank except for every fifth date. For instance:

```
plotdate = []
for idx, val in enumerate(date):
    if idx%5 == 0:
        plotdate.append(val)
    else:
        plotdate.append('')
```

And then just use the plotdate list in your call to plt.xticks rather than the date variable. That seemed to work for me.